# Abrir modal em toda tela e não dentro do iframe

Tags: javascript, html, semântica

Olá, tenho um iframe, e dentro dele tem um modal usando semantic, quero saber como faço e se é possível para abrir esse modal na tela toda, e não dentro do próprio iframe, já pesquisei e não encontrei nada, só sei que com link se usa `target="_parent"` estou chamando o modal assim :

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(){
    $('#modal5.modal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<button data-modal="modal5" id="call-modal-5" class="ui secondary button">teste</button>

<div class="ui basic modal" id="modal5">
  <div class="ui icon header">
    <i class="archive icon"></i>
    Ola
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>mensagem para teste</p>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: Estilizar a mdal com posição absoluta top:0px e left:0px, e definir height e width como 100% deve resolver

Comment: tentei, não resolveu, a posição como absoluta só serve para a própria pagina do iframe, creio eu.

Comment: Ja tentou colocar como fixed ?

Comment: Se ele ta dentro de um iframe dentro de uma página o tamanho dele ficará limitado ao tamanho e posição do iframe.. Não tem como remover o iframe e manusear esse modal individualmente não?

Comment: fixed também não da certo, é igual o Marlysson falou, ta se limitando ao iframe, e não tem como remover o iframe por que tava dando muitos conflitos com os arquivos Bootstrap.